# Can air pressure change the tension on a string?

Tags: pressure, string

I realize this may be offered simply for this forum, but it seems every guitar player/website/forum agrees that you have to slacken the tension on your guitar strings before going on an airplane, otherwise the change in pressure may cause the guitar neck to snap from increased string tension.

Comment: What does air pressure got to do with guitar strings?

Comment: I think it's more to the air humidity than from the air pressure.

Comment: Do you think increased humidity would increase or decrease the strain on the guitar neck?

Comment: Less humidity more tension.

Comment: Humidity and air pressure are bogus explanations by someone looking for an explanation but never doing the experiment or analyzing what the real affect of humidity changes might be. Temperature variation and more importantly, vibrations and and shock movements, are valid concerns when looking at a system under high stress/strain.

Answer (score 4):

**Air pressure** doesn't have much to do with the tension on the strings. The main reason that people are advised to slacken guitar strings before boarding a flight has to do with **temperature**.

As you might know, steel has a higher coefficient of thermal expansion than wood. This means that when the temperature of your guitar's environment decreases, the strings contract more than the wood. This can cause the strings (or even the neck) to snap.

It's not necessary to slacken the strings if you are sure that the interior of the aircraft *and your destination* are not much cooler than your present location.